Failed lookup for key [site_header] when extending admin/change_list.html
i tried to extend change_list.html template from using this two guide
https://hakibenita.com/how-to-turn-django-admin-into-a-lightweight-dashboard
&
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template
this is my view
@admin.register(summery)
class StaisticsSummery(ModelAdmin):
     change_list_template ="admin/stat_summary_change_list.html"
     def changelist_view(self, request,extra_context=None):
          extra_context = extra_context or {}
          filterUser = request.GET.get("q","")
          filterStart  = request.GET.get("startDate","")
          filterEnd  = request.GET.get("endDate","")
          if filterStart=="":
               filterStart = "1300-01-01"
          if filterEnd=="":
               filterEnd = "1500-12-29"
          result =  list(User.objects.values("username").annotate(
               total_Balance=Sum('statistics__balance',default=0,filter=Q(statistics__created_at__gte=filterStart)|Q(statistics__created_at__lte=filterEnd)),
...)
          ).order_by("username"))
          if(filterUser!="" and filterUser is not None):
               result =result.filter(username=filterUser)
          extra_context["result"]=result
          return  super().changelist_view(request,extra_context)

i request when there was'nt any  start and end to querystring  everything looks works fine and  all result are valid
i use the given query in django shell an everything were valid but somehow opt context variable is changing when trying to query with dates via the browser
is there any better way to debug this problem related to context object
